# Automate downloading datasets via Colab

Tags: python, dataset, colab, scraping

My desktop computer recently broke, and I'm currently working on a small laptop with barely 500mb of space left. I need to download about 100gb of files from the DFAUST dataset. I was wondering if there was a way to write a script that did this.

Wget doesn't work because the downloads must be done on the website itself behind a login. Is there a way to use a form of data scraping to get behind this and automate the download process?

If not, what are your suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: where is this DFAUST located ? on colab ? colab uses your google drive - there are python libraries where you can connect to your gdrive and download/uppload

Comment: DFAUST is located at https://dfaust.is.tue.mpg.de and one must log in to download content. It requires that you download it from the site directly

Comment: And can you remind me why you cant/dont want to download it manually ? just to understand the problem better

Comment: Firstly, I do not have the disk space on my computer. And although I have flash drives laying around, there is something lacking with my network. I live in Guam, and for some reason everything else takes a while to download and upload. On top of that, the downloads have consistently failed just as they're about to finish. So far I have successfully downloaded and uploaded to my GDrive one of ten datasets.

Comment: how did you download that one to your Gdrive ? one of the reason they have not made it possible to download directly using wget or other is the load on their server ... I don't think it is possible to download it in a programing way - if you succeeded come back and enlighten us :)

Comment: I plugged in a flash drive, manually downloaded the dataset from the website using my browser, then uploaded the files. Total time: more than 24 hours. Living in the middle of the ocean doesn't make things easier. Thank you for your assistance though @user702846

Comment: here is an alternative - get an aws instance with GUI - through the aws instance download the files (manually again) - it would be much faster - then using your python download from the aws bucket where you have downloaded for slow but stable download ...